# Can't Access to a control in main window from static method

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

I make public static function to have access to my main window controls from another window ( lets say a thing like tool box)
And I added this method:

```
public static void GoToLibraryPage()
{

    MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Library_Pg());
}
```

I have a control (frame) named MainFrame in same window:

```
 <Grid>
        <Frame x:FieldModifier="Public"  x:Name="MainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
    </Grid>
```

The error is :

> an object instance required for the nonstatic field

it seems funny but I think I don't know the basics. how can I access to it?

**Update:**
I made an instance of my main window like this:

```
  public static void GoToLibraryPage()
        {

            MainWindow mmm= new MainWindow();
           mmm.MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Library_Pg());

        }
```

by doing this nothing had happened but a new error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException'
>   occurred in System.dll

Comment: Learn about classes.  You need an instance of your window.

Comment: Ok, thanks. that helped.

Comment: First-chance exceptions are only a problem if they aren't handled.

Comment: yes thats true but beside that and In my case making an new instance just make another Main Window that can be shown with show method. but the task will not be done. I cant navigate to another page.

Comment: You need to get your existing instance.

Comment: Thank you. <3 . in my case the answer is : MainWindow existingMainWindwoInstance= Window.GetWindow(Application.Current.MainWindow) as MainWindow;

Comment: `Application.Current.MainWindow` is a `Window`; you don't need that.

Comment: yes I tried that in first place but it didn't work. and I don't know why. it does not contain my controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I should change my question title but, lets accept it it for now.
For get access to Main window controls, We should get existing class of main window. but some things like this for the reasons that I cant understand didn't work for me:

```
(Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow)
```

but this worked and the answer in my case is :

```
 MainWindow ExistingInstanceOfMainWindow= Window.GetWindow(Application.Current.MainWindow) as MainWindow;
```

If anyone could explain why, feel free to add your knowledge to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need...

```
(Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Library_Pg());
```

Generally it is considered bad form to access methods in this way...but everyone does it.